# Anscheinend falsche Verwendung von „um … zu“

Tags: infinitive, subordinate-clause

Auf Facebook-Seiten wird dem Benutzer vorgeschlagen:

> Freunde einladen, um diese Seite mit „Gefällt mir“ zu markieren

Mir ist nicht klar, warum hier *um … zu* verwendet wird. Ich verstehe diesen Satz so, als würde er im Englischen bedeuten: „Invite friends in order to ‘like’ this page“. Also „Freunde einladen, damit *du* diese Seite mit ‚Gefällt mir‘ markieren kannst“.

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Final.html) nach:

> Das zum Infinitiv gehörende Subjekt kann sich nicht auf das Objekt des Hauptsatzes beziehen:
>
> NICHT: *Der Hauswart rief einen Klempner, um den Abfluss zu reparieren.*
>   NICHT: *Die Eltern schicken das Kind zur Schule, um etwas zu lernen.*

Ist der Satz bei Facebook einfach falsch? Wäre nicht der richtige:

> Freunde einladen, <strike>um</strike> diese Seite mit „Gefällt mir“ zu markieren

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja, ein offensichtlicher <s>Grammatik</s>fehler. Es ist ein typischer Fehler von englischen Muttersprachlern; wahrscheinlich wurde dieser Satz von jemandem übersetzt, der den Tag über mehr Englisch als Deutsch benutzt. (Das trifft bei Facebook wahrscheinlich auch auf manche deutsche Muttersprachler zu.)

Comment: Ein gut bekanntes Phänomen der Zeit kaum professioneller Übersetzer, die ihren Dienst online bieten. In der hebräischsprachigen Welt ist die Katastrophe noch größer.

Comment: Ich sehe es nicht irgendwie als schwaches Deutsch, da das Englische ja mehrdeutig ist.  Eher so ein Fall wo der Übersetzer ohne den eigentlichen Zusammenhang arbeiten musste, und ihm die richtige Interpretation nicht einfiel oder er sich halt entscheiden musste.  Dumm aber so läuft es in der Tat ganz oft.

Comment: @AdamM.B.: Ja, das könnte natürlich auch sein. Dann hat der Übersetzer aber rein mechanisch gearbeitet, denn wie das *liken* bei Facebook funktioniert, wissen ja inzwischen sogar Verweigerer wie ich.

Comment: Ja, genau.  Dies hier ist wohl ein Sonderfall wo eine Beschreibung des Strings kaum notwendig ist.

Comment: Grammatikfehler? Der Satz ist grammatikalisch absolut korrekt. Das ist ein *Übersetzungsfehler*

Comment: @addy2012: Es gibt zwei Arten von Grammatikfehlern: 1. ungrammatische Wortfolgen und 2. grammatische Sätze, die nicht das Beabsichtigte ausdrücken.

Comment: @HansAdler Sehr merkwürdige Definition. Wenn Ihnen das Ihr Linguistikprofessor so erzählt hat, dann akzeptiere ich das aber. Für mich sind Grammatikfehler nur *Syntaxfehler*, keine "*Semantikfehler*".

Comment: @addy2013: Ich bezweifle ja, dass sich ernsthafte Linguisten damit beschäftigen, zu definieren, was man unter *Grammatikfehler* verstehen soll. Ist mir jedenfalls in der Linguistik noch nicht begegnet. Laien verwenden den Begriff aber jedenfalls inklusiv, zumal sie ihn meist vor allem aus dem von Lehrern benutzten Fehlerzeichen *Gr* kennen, das z.B. auch für semantisch unpassendes Tempus verwendet wird. Im Kontext dieser Frage ist die formale Definition einer Sprache als Menge von grammatischen Sätzen sowieso unpassend.

Comment: @HansAdler Also ich kenne *T* für (semantische) Tempusfehler. Aber egal.

Comment: Da es natürlich tatsächlich ein Fehler im Grenzbereich von Grammatik und Semantik ist und sich *offensichtlich* natürlich nicht auf die Klassifizierung sondern nur auf die Fehlerhaftigkeit beziehen sollte, hab ich das jetzt entsprechend korrigiert. Danke für den Hinweis! Tut mir Leid, dass ich da erst etwas auf dem Schlauch stand.

Answer (score 3):

Wie Hans und Canoonet.eu schon geschrieben haben, bedeutet die Konstruktion Folgendes:

> Tu *X*, um *Y* zu *verb*.
>
> Wenn du *X* tust, wird dir *Y* *verben*.

Also anhand der Beispiele der Frage:

> Die Eltern schickten das Kind zur Schule, um etwas zu lernen.
>
> Die Eltern haben etwas gelernt, indem sie ihr Kind zur Schule geschickt haben.

Folglich kann man den Satz nur verstehen als:

> Wenn du das hier *liken* möchtest, musst du dafür Freunde einladen.

Ich weiß nicht, was Facebook mit diesem Satz ausdrücken möchte (ich selbst bin nicht dabei), vermute aber, dass Folgendes gemeint ist:

> Teile deinen Freunden davon mit, damit sie es mit »Gefällt mir« markieren können.

Wenn das gemeint ist, würde deine Ersatzübersetzung ohne *um* immer noch nicht hinhauen, denn das würde eher bedeuten:

> Freunde einladen, diese Seite mit »Gefällt mir« zu markieren.
>
> Lade deine Freunde zu dir ein, damit ihr gemeinsam »Gefällt mir« drücken könnt.

Es wäre zwar ein bisschen näher dran (immerhin bist du dann nicht mehr der Gefallen Findende) aber immer noch etwas quer.

Answer (score 1):

> Freunde einladen, um diese Seite mit „Gefällt mir“ zu markieren

is perfectly normal German, it just doesn't mean what the author most likely wanted to express. It means something like

> To invite friends over for the purpose of liking a page on Facebook

So it evokes the image of having a bunch of people sit around with wine and chips as if to play games or watch soccer, but instead they press the *Like* button on facebook. The most likely intended phrase was indeed

> Freunde einladen, diese Seite mit „Gefällt mir“ zu markieren

If you wish to, I could go into why this is so - what about the (lack of the) *um* brings about this meaning.

Comment: I understand why it's so. I haven't thought of such interpretation though (see my own interpretation in the question which is just as ridiculous).

Comment: Of course, the question is whether phrasing a sentence which clearly doesn't express the author's original intention is a grammatical mistake although grammatically correct...

Comment: I would say so; it results from misusing/misunderstanding grammar, regardless of the result being grammatically applicable. In the GG branch of linguistics, this is sometimes discussed as the difference between surface vs. structural equivalence; the surface form expressed corresponds to a grammatical structure, but not to the grammatical structure that was intended.

Comment: Nein, ich folge deiner Interpretation nicht. Der Satz bedeutet ganz klar »Lade Freunde ein, damit du diese Seite mit ›Gefällt mir‹ markieren kannst.«

Comment: Ja, das ist eine andere mögliche Interpretation. Bzgl. meiner, denk: Freunde einladen, um den Kuchen zu essen. Syntaktisch das gleiche.

Comment: Auch da sehe ich in der Hauptsache, dass *ich* den Kuchen esse. Ich würde zum Beispiel nie Freunde einladen, um Pilze zu essen ;).

Comment: Ja, aber gemeinsam - das ist, was ich meine. Man sitzt gemeinsam und isst Kuchen/schaut Fußball/liked auf Facebook.